# show google ads in for loop in django template?

Tags: python, django, adsense

How to show the ads in between for loop ?
is this possible?
is this good way to show ads?

below my code is not working inside for loop

```
{% for branch_obj in branch_list %}
        <div>cards</div>

        {% if  forloop.counter == 2 %}

            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                        <!-- squre for blog -->
                        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                            style="display:block"
                            data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
                            data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"
                            data-ad-format="auto"
                            data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
                        <script>
                            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                        </script>

         {% endif %}


  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: define not working.

Comment: ads not showing if use this code inside for loop

Comment: First of all, don't load the script inside the forloop. You just need to define it once. Then, check the console if this script is loading properly.

Comment: sorry i was need to add width 100% in class="adsbygoogle"